# What is the difference between concatenate, appending and merge on SAS?

Tags: sas

I am trying to run codes on SAS for Concatenate, Appending and Merge and unable to understand the difference between the same. Looking for some one to help me understand the same with examples.

Comment: You should rearrange your question: it is on charge to you write the code you have and exposing your doubt about it. If not, you should search for a tutorial/guide elsewhere from StakOverflow.

Comment: I disagree; there's nothing wrong with asking about fundamental terminology on SO.  I'd like to see more research done before asking for such a simple topic, but asking about the idea is perfectly fine.

Comment: You forgot the word join ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Concatenate** and **Append** are similar, but not used the same way.  In SAS, **Append** is used most commonly to mean *concatenation in place*.  In other words, adding rows to a dataset without reading in the original dataset.  This is very efficient, as you skip reading one of the datasets, but it has limitations (largely, you can't interleave or do other data step type things while appending).  Append is most often done by `PROC APPEND`.

**Concatenate**, on the other hand, while it can mean *appending*, is usually used when *combining the rows from two datasets into a new dataset with all of the rows from each source dataset as separate rows*, but not in-place.  This would be done with a `set` statement in a data step, most commonly.  This reads both datasets in and writes a new dataset (that could replace one of the original input datasets, or have a new name).  Concatenate also is often used to mean combine two *string* values into a variable; that's actually the most common usage I've heard it in.

**Merge** is not the same at all, though; it is side-by-side in some fashion, placing the data from one dataset in new variables on the same rows as the data from the other dataset.  New rows *can* be created as part of merge, when one dataset has different key identifier values from the other, but that's usually not the point of the merge (usually!).  Merge is done most often in the data step, either with the `merge` or the `update` statement.

Concatenate and Merge can also be done in other ways, of course, including SQL.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning interleaving as a hybrid of concatenating / merging? i.e. a `set` statement with multiple datasets plus a `by` statement, as opposed to `merge` + `by`.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

**Concatenate**: add a dataset on top (or to the bottom) of another one. Look into the `SET` statement of the `DATA Step` or the `UNION` clause of `PROC SQL`.

**Append**: Just another word for concatenate. Look into `PROC DATASETS` / `APPEND`, but it accomplishes the same task with different means.

**Merge**: add a dataset to the side (right, generally) of another one. Look into the `MERGE` statement of the `DATA Step` and/or the various `JOIN`'s allowed by `PROC SQL`.

SAS Documentation will show you plenty of examples!

Answer (score 0):

concatenate :it is used to append observations from one data set to another data set,so you specify a list of data set names in the set statement,to concatenate two data set the SAS system must process all observations from both data sets to create a new one.

APPEND:bypasses the observations from original data set and add the new observations directly at the end of the original data set when you have different variables you use the force=option with the append procedure.It function the same way as the append statement in the datasets statement.
and you can only append one data set at a time while in concatenation you can add as many data set in the set statement.

MERGE:you should have a common variable or several variables which taken together uniquely identify each observations,it sequentaly checks observation for each by-value(you have to sort your data sets before you can merge them),then write the combined observation to the new data set