# How to save obj in db in laravel(mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, stdclass

I am concatenating 2 variables

1. $link1 --- object
2. $mynewvalue ---- array

```
$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $link1, $mynewvalue);
$settings->value = $obj_merged;

$settings->save();
```

Error:

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

I am completely confused of this can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you're looking for. Are you trying to keep all information about  `$obj_merged` in the settings table? Is that value serialized in the table? How are you getting `$link` to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) for models. Add a `protected $casts` array to your `Setting` model:

```
class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $casts = ['value' => 'object'];

    // Class properties and methods
}
```

This will automatically handle serializing and unserializing this property for you.

This will also let you skip the step of casting the array to an object before setting the value and would cast to an object behind the scenes for you allowing you to do:

```
$settings->value = array_merge((array) $link1, $mynewvalue);

$settings->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your example, you can serialize your object using `serialize` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php

Or encode it in JSON using `json_encode`
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php

Saving serialized objects or JSON-encoded objects are really the best thing to do if you are trying to search in these values.

Finally, what you are trying to do is not concatenation, but merging (that's not the same thing). See [What is the difference between concatenate, appending and merge on SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175884/what-is-the-difference-between-concatenate-appending-and-merge-on-sas) for more information about the concatenation / merging differences